# Custom tab not highlighting

Tags: android

I would like to show count in the tab just like WhatsApp.
[image]

I added a custom view to the tab and I could implement somewhat like this. The problem I am facing now is, when the page loads, the first tab is not highlighted. When I swipe the viewpager to the next tab and then comesback it is highlighted.

I am setting a color selector as text color for the text view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/white" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/white" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_active="true"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_active="false"
        android:color="@color/inactive_tab_color" />
    <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And this is the tab layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/inactive_tab_color"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />
```

I have tried `getTabLayout().getTabAt(0).select()` and `viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)` but not working. The tab is not getting highlighted.

Can anyone guid me what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: Nobody has any answers?

Comment: If my question is not clear enough, I can explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this issue.

At the place of initialising tabs, I put code for selecting the second tab first and then the first tab. As these code run before the page comes to view to the user, he/she will not feel flickering of the tab.

I know this is not the best method. This is just a work around. But as I didn't get any other solution, I went for this. The code snippet is below.

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(v);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
```

Add the above code at the place of initialising tabs. `onActivityCreated()` in the case of fragments and `onCreate()` in the case of Activity.